# Comparing two date objects in Python: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'method'

Tags: python, date, datetime

This shouldn't be too difficult but I can't seem to get it to work. 
I want to compare two datetime.date types in Python but I keep getting a Type Error:

```
from datetime import date  

class Vacancy(object):
    def __init__(self, date): #date is a datetime string of format 2017-13-03T00.00.000Z
        self.date = datetime.strptime(date[:-1], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').date()

    def getDate(self):
         return self.date


all_objects = [o1, o2, o3, o4, ...] #contains objects of type Vacancy
for o in all_objects:
    earliestDate = date(2020, 1, 1) 
    if o.getDate() < earliestDate:
        earliestDate = o.getDate()

print(earliestDate)
```

`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'method'`

Which doesn't make sense to me because:
    `print(type(earliestDate))` and `print(type(o.getDate()))`  both give
`<class 'datetime.date'>`

What could I be doing wrong?

EDIT: added class sample code for the objects in all_objects

EDIT2: As many of you pointed out it is indeed a missing '()'. In my actual code I was assigning the method instad of the value by doing `earliestDate = o.getDate`. Next time I'll try to be more truthful to my code. Thank you all for the insight you provided as I indeed come from Java and I don't fully comprehend Python yet.

Comment: `type(o.getDate)` or `type(o.getDate())`?

Comment: My bad type(o.getDate())

Comment: Could you provide an [mcve] that illustrates your problem? What are `o1`,`o2` etc? Are you sure that `if o.getDate() < earliestDate:` doesn't read `if o.getDate < earliestDate:` in your actual code?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you missed the `()` somewhere, maybe `earliestDate = o.getDate`? Hard to say since this is not your actual code.

Comment: Are you comparing a date value with a datetime value?

Comment: @SiHa I have added some code that explains how I get the date from the objects in all_objects . I don't think I am missing '()' somewhere.

Comment: Well, the code above is *still* not an MCVE: You haven't shown how you instantiate the objects, and the datetime string is wrong in many ways. However, if I add  this: `o1 = Vacancy('2017-03-13T00:00:00.000Z')` and the change the list to a single entry, `[o1]`, your code runs just fine, for me.

Comment: use `@property` named `date` instead of `getDate()` method (in this case a simple attribute access is enough even without `@property`).

Comment: it looks like you might be used to Java (the getter)? Have you looked at [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) it could help you track down this type of problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `TypeError` should give you all information you need to solve this problem. Here's how to interpret it:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'method'
```

- The `'<' not supported` means that you got the error when using the `<` operator, as you already know.
- The comparison doesn't work because one of the things you are comparing is not a `datetime.date` instance. You already got this, too.
- The `method` type is what you get if you would use `o.getDate` instead of `o.getDate()`. In Python you can pass around methods as values if you like, just like lambdas or functions. This is not what you want in this case however, so make sure you use `()` everywhere you want to call a method, even if it doesn't take any arguments.
- The order of the types in the error message is also interesting. That `datetime.date` comes before `method` mean that the date was on the **left** side and the problematic value was on the **right** side. In your case, the `earliestDate` is holding a `method` instead of a `datetime.date`.
- Now that we know that `earliestDate` is the problem, where is it updated? `earliestDate = date(2020, 1, 1)` is clearly a date, but how about `earliestDate = o.getDate()`? It's using parentheses, so `o.getDate()` must be returning a `method`.
- Given your code, the `Vacancy` will always have `self.date` set to a date, or an exception will be thrown (something like `ValueError: time data 'xxx' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'`). I'm guessing your code looks different and the initialization for `Vacancy` is wrong somehow. This is the benefit of providing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) :)

Comment: Your succint and clean way of finding the problem helped me out a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You overwritten the definition of date, try this (maintaining the datetime namespace with an alias: dt). A good practice would be to not name local or member variables with the same name of functions and objects of the libraries you import (you imported date from datetime and then use `date` as the argument of the init).

```
import datetime as dt   

class Vacancy(object):
    def __init__(self, date):
        self.date = date

    def getDate(self):
         return self.date


all_objects = [o1, o2, o3, o4, ...] #contains objects of type Vacancy
for o in all_objects:
    earliestDate = dt.date(2020, 1, 1) 
    if o.getDate() < earliestDate:
        earliestDate = o.getDate()

print(earliestDate)
```

An extra observation is that in python there is no need of defining getters and setters, since the variables are public. It is better if you just:

```
import datetime as dt   

class Vacancy(object):
    def __init__(self, date):
        self.date = date

all_objects = [o1, o2, o3, o4, ...] #contains objects of type Vacancy
for o in all_objects:
    earliestDate = dt.date(2020, 1, 1) 
    if o.date < earliestDate:
        earliestDate = o.date
```

And if you want to be sure the date member variable is  not modified, you can do something like this:

```
class Vacancy(object):
    def __init__(self, date):
        self.date = date

    def getMinDate(self, other_date):
        if self.date < other_date:
            return dt.date(self.date)
        else:
            return other_date

all_objects = [o1, o2, o3, o4, ...] #contains objects of type Vacancy
earliestDate = dt.date(2020, 1, 1) 
for o in all_objects:
    earliestDate = o.getMinDate(earliestDate)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out how Python doesn't require getters/setters. As the above wasn't my actual code, it wasn't an issue with the date import. For me. the actual class code was in a different file

Answer (score 0):

#### **This error is also thrown when trying to apply the condition to NULL values in the column.**

To solve this:

- **Add a condition to only perform the condition when the values are NOT null.**
- **Remove the null values**

```py
from datetime import date  

class Vacancy(object):
    def __init__(self, date): #date is a datetime string of format 2017-13-03T00.00.000Z
        self.date = datetime.strptime(date[:-1], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').date()

    def getDate(self):
         return self.date


all_objects = [o1, o2, o3, o4, ...] #contains objects of type Vacancy
for o in all_objects:
    earliestDate = date(2020, 1, 1) 
    
    # NOT Null condition 
    if (o != None) and (earliestDate != None):
        if o.getDate() < earliestDate:
            earliestDate = o.getDate()

print(earliestDate)
```